# Backtrack sudoku in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

I'm trying to build a backtrack sudoku solver in Haskell. But I'm stuck at one of the final points. I created a function called nextBoards which returns all possible soduko boards where the next empty place is filled in with the possible values. Now I'm trying to use backtracking in Haskell, but I cannot use things like while-loops and now I'm really confused on how to do this. I've made a sudoku solver before in Java, but I'm completely stuck on how to do it in Haskell for the moment.

```
-- Generate the next boards for a given board
nextBoards :: Board -> [Board]
nextBoards b = 
    let position = findFirstEmpty b
    in [update z (snd position) (fst position) b | z <- options b (snd position) (fst position)]

-- We found the real solution
solve :: Board -> [Board] -> Board
solve focus options
    | not (notEmpty focus) = focus
-- We hit a dead path try the next option
solve focus options
    | solve (head options) (tail options)
-- We are solving the focus, generate the next boards
-- and save the rest in the options
solve focus options
    | solve (head (nextBoards focus)) (tail (nextBoards focus))
```

I really don't know on how to proceed.

Comment: You have a list of candidate boards, and a function that solves..

Comment: @n.m. Yes I know, I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: Further hint:  [filter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a backtracking solution over a (partial) solution space (like all possible `Board`s) `S` with a type signature like:

```
backtrack :: S -> [S]
```

With `S` the current state, and `[S]` the list of all valid boards. Now there are in general three possible options:

- We have found a state that is `solved`, we return a list (*singleton*) containing our solution:

  ```
  backtrack s | solved s = [s]
  ```
- We have found a dead trail, in that case we no longer put effort into it, and return an empty list:

  ```
              | invalid s = []
  ```
- or it is possible we have to deploy our solution further, we generate `children`: states that have advanced one step from `s`, and call backtrack recursively, we return the `concat` of all the `backtrack`s of these children:

  ```
              | otherwise = concatMap backtrack $ children s
  ```

Or putting it all together:

```
backtrack :: S -> [S]
backtrack s | solved s = [s]
            | invalid s = []
            | otherwise = concatMap backtrack $ children s
```

The `invalid` guard can be omitted by simply generating an empty list of `children` for `invalid` states (as your solution will probably do) or by preventing to ever generate invalid `Board`s.

Now grounding this for your problem, generating `children` would come down to your `nextBoards` function:

```
children = nextBoards
```

or prettifying your function a bit:

```
children :: Board -> [Board]
children s = [update s y x v | v <- options s y x]
    where (x,y) = findFirstEmpty s
```

Now the solve (or `backtrack`) method is defined as:

```
backtrack :: Board -> [Board]
backtrack s | not (notEmpty s) = [s]
            | otherwise = concatMap backtrack $ children s
```

`backtrack` will generate a list of *all* valid solved Sudoku boards (where the originally places filled in, remain filled in). The list is generated lazily, so if you want *one* valid solution, you can simply use `head`:

```
solve :: Board -> Board
solve = head . backtrack
```